# How to store data on one datanode based on specific criteria in hadoop?

Tags: java, hadoop

Is it possible to keep data on one datanode in hadoop, meaning it is not (or very limited like when it runs out of space) distributed across the system (replication is fine).
Like I keep record logs for every minute and store them in a folder structure on hadoop that looks like this:

> /year/month/day

Now I want to force hadoop to store e.g. every month folder on one (or more if space is exceeded) datanode only, so when I perform a read request the namenode should in the best case only return one datanode as the location of the data blocks.

Is this possible? How would an implementation in Java look like (like grouping all files based on the hash of the parent folders together on a datanode)? Or this this a hadoop configuration?

Comment: Rather than mess with replica counts, you could have these files laid out by Hive partitions. That would speed things up more than limiting your replicas if you have structured data like this

Comment: @cricket_007 Based on what I found "Hive [...] and is stored as a sub-directory within the table’s directory on HDFS." I already get a subfolder structure based on my java objects thanks to pail. Hive won't guarantee me that the data isn't widely spread across datanodes right?

Comment: Right, Hive stores in HDFS. Never heard about pail. And whatever Mapreduce you are doing Hive would be no different in its output, I was simply stating that bucketing/partitioning your data would allow quicker access. Overall, storing data on one datanode is never a good option as it yields a single point of failure. The replicas and computations attempt to be rack aware to minimize cluster bandwidth, so you shouldn't be concerned about namenode read requests.  https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.7.2/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-hdfs/HdfsDesign.html#Replica_Placement:_The_First_Baby_Steps

Comment: @cricket_007 Pail allows you to "sort" data based on an attribute in a folder structure. I am fine with replication, but that should only be used when one datanode indeed fails. But I guess HDFS already sorts it in the best possible way, so I shouldnt mess around with it

Comment: Replication is two-sided. Where the replicas exist and how many are needed to provide fault tolerance. If you read that link and the next few sections, it mentions Rack Awareness and how that reduces how data is shuffled around when a datanode fails and a replica is needed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Not possible at datanode level.*

For a single file you can make sure it get's pushed into one machine by setting the block size as more than the file size and replication factor as 1. Note that it will be applicable for one file only. You have to reset the block size back to default or else you'll end up having all the files in hdfs pushed with the new block size.

And this is not applicable for multiple files i.e, all files under one month falls under one datanode. Because if you use the above idea, you'll have one file(one day) stored in one machine, but the next day of the month data might be put under a different data node. And even if we find a work around to place multiple days file of same month under same datanode, it'll end up in different machines after hadoop load distribution.

*It's best to leave the low level data storage & distribution to hadoop.
If you are interested in selecting only limited set of data, like the case you have suggested, then it's better to go with some abstraction like hive and creating a partition based on month.*

Answer (score 0):

If you save a file only in one DN, there is high probability that you may loose the data. As DNs are generally less powerful commodity hardware. Anyway,You can set the replication factor as 1 using the below command.

```
hadoop fs -setrep 1 'file_name'
```

This will set the replication of a particular file.

Comment: I am generally fine with replication, I just want to make sure that the data is grouped together on as few notes as possible. Like datasetA on I and III, but not part1 of datasetA on I and II, part 2 of datasetA on IV and VI, ...